# Keep getting error "Unable to implement Repository method: RepoClass.updateAll(Iterable arg0). No possible implementations found."

Tags: java, micronaut-data

Using Micronaut data v3, I created the following simple classes:
MyEntity.java

```
package test;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Id;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.MappedEntity;

@MappedEntity
public class MyEntity {
    @id
    @GeneratedValue(GeneratedValue.Type.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String name;
}
```

MyRepo.java:

```
package test;
import io.micronaut.data.jdbc.annotation.JdbcRepository;
import io.micronaut.data.model.query.builder.sql.Dialect;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.MYSQL)
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

The project can build without above 2 classes. Once I add these 2 classes, I got the error
java: Unable to implement Repository method: MyRepo.updateAll(Iterable arg0). No possible implementations found.

Comment: I assume `@id`, lowercase `i` is a typo. Could you add your build file to the question? Did you follow a guide (like https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-jdbc-repository.html)?

Comment: @id was a formatting error. I use "io.micronaut.data.annotation.Id". I did follow the example, verified the file structure. I don't see any problem in the code either.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using the `MyRepo.updateAll`? Based on:
```
Unable to implement Repository method: MyRepo.updateAll(Iterable arg0). No possible implementations found.
```
Looks like you are are attempting to call `updateAll` as a static method (which doesn't exist) instead of an instance method.

Comment: Thanks @ShingJo . I resolved the problem. The root cause is annotationProcessorPaths in POM. My project is to upgrade Micronaut 1.x to 3.x. In the POM's annotationProcessorPaths, micronaut-data-processor version needs to update.